# Laravel : Login user without password

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-3

I am new to Laravel and it looks like a nice PHP framework. Going through the guide and various tutorials, I know how to login a user using the Auth class. However the Auth class requires a username and a password to login the user.

Now, if I am using Facebook Connect, after a successful authentication with facebook, I might be able to retrieve the user's details corresponding to the facebook ID I will have saved in the DB. However, for a facebook user, no passwords would be saved in the DB. So how do I log in the user with the Auth class?

In Codeigniter, I would have set the session data as follows:

```
$userdata = array(
    'logged_in' => true,
    'user_id' => $user_id
);
$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [guide](http://stephenradford.me/blog#/facebook-login-in-laravel) of how to do it and also a [bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/oneauth) what will allow you to connect your users with more oauth apis

Comment: Does the Oauth have same functionalities as facebook SDK, or is it just used for authentication? Sorry, must be a naive question, but am fairly new. For example, with the Facebook SDK, I can get the user's friends, photos, etc..

Comment: @WebNovice oneauth can do everything the SDK can, it uses the SDK, go for it.

Comment: @xtrimsky I have updated the link. I'd go for the bundle thought.